# Why are trees marked purple in the state of Texas?

Tags: united-states, forests, texas

I've recognized this a few times in Texas. Trees were more or less "professionally" painted purple. It appeared totally random to me but was too frequent to just take it as a plain tag from the owner (like, "I especially like this tree, I'll make it purple"). Does anybody know what the paint signals?

[image]

Comment: Nation Forest boundaries have cuts in the tree bark that are painted red ( in E TX).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Purple paint is a common means of indicating private property boundaries in a number of US states.  Some states use alternate colors such as orange or blue.  The paint may be considered the equivalent of a "no trespassing" sign, but is considered more practical for marking property lines that may extend for miles.

There are usually requirements associated with the markings.  For example, Texas law (Penal Code §30.05) requires:

> (i) vertical lines of not less than eight inches in length and not less than one inch in width;
>   (ii)  placed so that the bottom of the mark is not less than three feet from the ground or more than five feet from the ground; and
>   (iii)  placed at locations that are readily visible to any person approaching the property and no more than:
>   (a)  100 feet apart on forest land;  or
>   (b)  1,000 feet apart on land other than forest land

Ref: **Purple Paint - Texas No Trespassing Marking** from [geocachingaustin.com](http://www.geocachingaustin.com/reference/purplepaint-texasnotrespassingmarking)